# keep the other div's separate from the animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to keep navitems 2 and 3 from moving while navitem 1 goes through its animation on mouse enter and leave does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible to even do this the way I'm trying to do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/xLbLrmcq/

Here's my html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Art Profile</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navitem" id="navitem1">
      <div id="navtext1">
        Work
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navitem" id="navitem2">
      Home
    </div>
    <div class="navitem" id="navitem3">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navitem1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#navitem1').animate({
      height: '+=25px',
      width: '+=20px',
    }).css({
      'border-top': '7px solid #008cb1'});
    $('#navtext1').css({
      'line-height': '3.5em',
      '-ms-transition':'.3s',
      '-moz-transition':'.3s',
      '-webkit-transition':'.3s'
    });
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#navitem1').animate({
      height: '-=25px',
      width: '-=20px',
    }).css({
      'border-top': '4px solid #008cb1'});
    $('#navtext1').css({
      'line-height': '2.5em',
      '-ms-transition':'.3s',
      '-moz-transition':'.3s',
      '-webkit-transition':'.3s'
    });
  });
});
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: #101010;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navitem {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 110px;
  background-color: #383838;
  color: #008cb1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top: 4px solid #008cb1;
  line-height: 2.5em;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either remove the width animations or find a way to keep the menu elements centered and aligned without using inline-block. Check the fiddle below for an example.

Be aware that you should also remove queued animations with:

```
$('#navitem1').stop()
```

Check the updated fiddle :

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/rfzf6z8z/)